# Any easy-to-use hash function in Win32 to hash an ASCII string?

Tags: c++, windows, security, hash

> Any easy-to-use hash function in Win32 to hash an ASCII string?

I'm looking for a simple hash function in Windows (preferable `kernel32.dll` or some other widely used DLL) to hash ASCII strings into, say, `DWORD`'s?

The function should be called from either C/C++ or x86 assebmly.

I've been Googling around, but there doesn't seem to be any functions that fit into my needs?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Isn't dword just an unsigned int?

Comment: Yeah, `DWORD` is just the Windows term.

Comment: Not just a term. A specific one AFAIK. Hence my question. How do you envision something hashing to "just a number"?

Comment: Because, a hash function normally takes variable-size inputs and hash them to a fixed-size output? Like, e.g., {0,1}^* -> {0,1}^k.

Comment: Yes and I just gave you all the pointers to look for it yourself. Also think about possible collisions.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for something simpler than the whole suite of Win32 functions, like `CryptCreateHash`.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this missing some context? Where do you want to call this hash function from? From a program? From command line? Something else?

Comment: From a C++ program.

Comment: It's not just you @Kjartan I have the feeling OP didn't really think this true at best and a huge [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at worst.

Comment: [`HashData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759853(v=vs.85).aspx) is very fast and simple. However, I
t is not cryptographically secure.

Comment: Thanks, I just need a simple message digest algorithm.

Comment: @RaymondChen, do you know what idea `HashData` is based on? Also, how do you know it is cryptographically insecure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is sample program demonstrating the use of `HashData` function in `Shlwapi.dll`.

This function is very simple and flexibile (both in input and output).

It basically performs a message digest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

using namespace std;

#define HASH_LEN 32

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* data = "foobarbaz";
  unsigned char hash[HASH_LEN] = {0};

  HashData((LPBYTE)data, strlen(data),(LPBYTE)hash, HASH_LEN);

  printf("Hash: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < HASH_LEN; i++) {
    printf("%d ", hash[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find [LHashValOfNameSys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inside `OleAut32.dll`

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    printf(
        "%s = %08x\r\n"
        , argv[1]
        , LHashValOfNameSys( 0, 0, (const OLECHAR *) argv[1] )
    );

    // Done
    return 0;
}
```